# Elastic beanstalk acessing external datacenter with unique ip

Tags: networking, proxy, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the following scenario:

- Elastic beanstalk with N instances
- ELB for load balancing to the EBS
- External datacenter with IP Filtering

Since I can't filter by name (fqdn) and I can't filter for a single IP either, is there a way to make all the request that came from AWS Machines have only one IP or maybe use a third machine to serve as proxy for the calls for the AWS Machines and then attach a EIP on it.

Comment: What kind of calls?  If they are just messages, can you dump them to a queue, and have your datacenter poll the queue?

Comment: a synch call that dispatch a huge ammount of sms on the the other point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. Or at least, if there's a way to do it, I'd love to hear about it. One of the biggest problems with beanstalk is its requirement to exist outside of VPCs, and thus, in arbitrary Amazon IP space. About the only workaround I've found for this after talking to AWS engineers is to forward traffic from them to something like a bastion server, and allow the bastion server to communicate with your data center firewall. Maybe there's something I'm missing, but I know of no other way to get it working without some server in between the beanstalk instances and the data center; not if the IP of the server matters.

Comment: Yeah, found nothing on it and probably gonna use a t1.micro for peer traffic :/.

Comment: Giving the bounty bonus to you